# problem to find and element: Selenium can't find a specific button on the page

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having problem to find an element on the page, I tried by xpath, ID, Css and nothing works.

```
    # Button Filter Find
    sleep(30)

    chrome.find_element(By.ID, "ext-comp-1136").click()

    app = tk.Tk()
    numerocb = sd.askstring('Número CB', 'NUM_REFERENCIA_CB', parent=app)
    chrome.find_element(By.ID, "ext-comp-1136").send_keys("numerocb")
    chrome.find_element(By.ID, "ext-comp-1136").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The page take a while to load, so I need to wait until the element "Filter Button " is available to click and then search by number.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML

Comment: Can you share the webpage URL to see the HTML.